# Frida javascript Error > TypeError: cannot set property 'implementation' of undefined

Tags: android, frida

I got error when Calling the function on frida script on certain package.

Here is the java:

```
package com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common;


public final class CommonUtils {

    public static boolean m5568(Context context) {
        boolean r3 = m5582(context);
        String str = Build.TAGS;
        if ((!r3 && str != null && str.contains("test-keys")) || new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk").exists()) {
            return true;
        }
        File file = new File("/system/xbin/su");
        if (r3 || !file.exists()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

And this is my frida script:

```
Java.perform(function(){
    console.log("[ * ] Starting implementation override...");

     var crashlyticsx = Java.use("com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CommonUtils");

     crashlyticsx.m5568.implementation = function(a){
        // Change the return value to "false"
        console.log("[ * ] m5568 to false..." );

        return false
    }
});
```

And this is the error:

```
TypeError: cannot set property 'implementation' of undefined
```

Comment: Which tool has generated the decompiled Java code of `CommonUtils`? Are you sure it has not renamed the method? Alternatively make sure there is no overloaded version of method `m5568`.

Comment: I'm using JADX, so how to detect the real function name?

Comment: Recent Jadx versions include the original name in comments next to the class/method name (if the method has been renamed).

Answer (score 0):

I think `m5568` name is *renamed* by tools.
Try to check `smali` source file and find the real function name.